# How to draw a rectangle on a Leaflet map from GeoJSON data

Tags: leaflet, geojson, cartography

I am trying to draw a rectangle on a Leaflet map with JSON data which looks like this.

```
    var geojsonfeatures = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
    {"type":"Feature",
        "geometry":{"type":"Polygon",
                    "coordinates":"[[354,844],[425,933]]"},
        "properties":{"name":"area1"}
    }
    ]};
```

The coordinates need to be transformed which if it was a Point could be done like this:

```
    coordsToLatLng: function (newcoords) {
    return (map.unproject([newcoords[0], newcoords[1]], map.getMaxZoom()));
            }
```

I am lost as to how to do this for an array of Points.  coordsToLatLngs look like it would be the right one but not sure how to use it.  Or is it geometryToLayer?

Answer (score 5):

To start off, a rectangle in GeoJSON needs *five* coordinates: the four corners, and the last one duplicating the first, to close the polygon (this is a common convention for many spatial formats) - in your example, you only have two.

Secondly, the `coordinates` property in the `geometry` should be an array, not a string, like this:

```
"coordinates":[[354,844],[425,933]]
```

A polygon also contains several linear rings, with basic polygons only containing a single linear ring. It should look like this:

```
"coordinates":[[[354,844],[425,844],[425,933],[354,933],[354,844]]]
```

A cleaned up version of the GeoJSON would look like this:

```
{
  "type":"FeatureCollection",
  "features":[
    {
      "type":"Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type":"Polygon",
        "coordinates":[[[354,844],[425,844],[425,933],[354,933],[354,844]]]
      },
      "properties":{"name":"area1"}
    }
  ]
}
```

Next, the coordinates seem weird, even if they are projected coordinates. Where did you get them from? They are most likely very, *very* close to the upper left corner of the map; for example, doing the inverse of what you do with the default example of Leaflet's site gives this:

```
> map.project(map.getCenter(), map.getMaxZoom())
o.Point {x: 33524792.251733333, y: 22316128.857322786}
```

Note that the coordinates are several orders of magnitudes larger than your coordinates.

Other than that, it looks like it should work.

Comment: I ended up changing the type to a MultiPoint (from Polygon) - that means the 5th point to close the polygon is not needed.  Thanks for your advise.

With the 2 points, I was able to create the rectangle.